# Async post request and assigning returned data

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

So I am learning AngularJS and I am trying to replace my not-so-pretty method of getting data from a webservice and realtime assinging it to a variable that is binded using ng-repeat. The thing I want to achieve mostly is to have asynchronous call. I can't use it now because AJAX is returning data after data is returned to a scope variable.

My current code looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module("Listt", []);

    app.controller(
        "ListtController",
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.results = {
            response: [{
                name: '',
                surname: '',
                age: ''
            }]
        };
        $scope.searchListt = function () {
            loadingAnimationStart();
            $scope.results = getListt();
            loadingAnimationStop();
        };

        function getListt() {
            var returnData;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'listt',
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: {
                    age_from: $('[name="age-start"]').val(),
                    age_to: $('[name="age-end"]').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {                
                    returnData = JSON.parse(data);
                }
            });
            return returnData;
        }
    }
);
```

And in HTML I indicate search function by using ng-click

```
<button ng-click="searchListt()">Search</button>
```

Comment: The entire stuff your doing inside `getListt()` function should ideally come under something called "services" in angular. Also instead of ajax calls make use of `$http` inbuilt service of angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `angularJs` then you should use `$http.post`

```
var app = angular.module("Listt", []);

        app.controller(
            "ListtController",
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.results = {
                response: [{
                    name: '',
                    surname: '',
                    age: ''
                }]
            };
            $scope.searchListt = function () {
                loadingAnimationStart();
                $scope.results = getListt();
                loadingAnimationStop();
            };

            function getListt() {
                $scope.returnData;
                $http.post(url, data, config).then(function (response) {
                 $scope.returnData = JSON.parse(response)
                },function (response) {
                alert("ERROR")
                });
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code here. `getListt();` function call from `searchListt` function. Once ajax call will success then response data assign to `$scope.results`

```
var app = angular.module("Listt", []);

    app.controller(
        "ListtController",
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.results = {
            response: [{
                name: '',
                surname: '',
                age: ''
            }]
        };
        $scope.searchListt = function () {
            loadingAnimationStart();
            getListt();

        };

        function getListt() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'listt',
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: {
                    age_from: $('[name="age-start"]').val(),
                    age_to: $('[name="age-end"]').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {                
                    $scope.results = JSON.parse(data);
                    loadingAnimationStop();
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this work great, but I still need async request

Comment: @plxhelpme_kindofuser it is still async request, once service request completed (execute when server response comes in success function inside ajax call)

Answer (score 0):

Why you cany directly call searchlist function and take variable. I think it will work.

```
$scope.results=[];

$scope.searchListt = function () {

           loadingAnimationStart();
           $.ajax({
                url: 'listt',
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: {
                    age_from: $('[name="age-start"]').val(),
                    age_to: $('[name="age-end"]').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {                
                     $scope.results = JSON.parse(data);
                     loadingAnimationStop();
                }


            });
           loadingAnimationStop();
        }
```